# How to remove quotes in TCL string by using 'string map'

Tags: csv, tcl, double-quotes

I am really stuck with this problem for some hours now. I am writing the output of my TCL script to a .csv file. Theoretically it should have 130 lines, but it stops afther line 117, where the first times double-quotes appear. So I want to remove the double-quotes using 'string map' but all the ways I tried it outputs still doublequotes. Other caharcters are cleanly maped as I intended.

```
set lines [string map [list "\;" {} "," {} {"} {} "\'" {} ] $lines]
set lines [string map [list "\;" {} "," {} "\"" {} {'} {} ] $lines]
set lines [string map [list "\;" {} "," {} \" {} \' {} ] $lines]
```

Has anyone an idea how to correctly remove double-quotes out of a string?

Thanks!
Paul

Comment: Could you put the problematic line in your question? The things you tried should work, so there must be something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Replacing quotes using `string map` is fine, but please don't use the basic string manipulation tools to process csv data, as you will get hard-to-detect errors from time to time. Using the [csv](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html "Procedures to handle CSV data.") package is much safer and in many ways more convenient.

Comment: @paul, note that single quotes have absolutely no special meaning in Tcl, and they do you require escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string map` calls you use will work — all are using correctly-constructed even-length maps — but it is possible that the characters you see in the input string are not standard double quotes (`"`) but rather their more sophisticated cousins (`“`, `”`). There are a few other characters that can look similar too, such as a naked diaeresis (`¨`).